# simplify linq query?

Tags: c#, linq

Can anyone simplify this to work very efficiently....

```
FileCompareLength myFileCompare1 = new FileCompareLength();
var queryList1Only3 = (from file in list1  select file).Except(list2, myFileCompare1 );
var queryList1Only33 = (from file in list2 select file).Except(list1, myFileCompare1 );
var difference1 = queryList1Only3.ToHashSet();
difference1.SymmetricExceptWith(queryList1Only33);
var query4 = difference1.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => x.Name);
if (query4.Count() > 0) {
    dest.WriteLine("Discrepancies in File Date:");
    foreach (var v in query4) {
        dest.WriteLine(v.Lengh+ "      " + v.FullName);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class FileCompareLength : System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<System.IO.FileInfo> {
    public FileCompareLength() { }
    public bool Equals(System.IO.FileInfo f1, System.IO.FileInfo f2) {
        return (f1.Length == f2.Length);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(System.IO.FileInfo fi) {
        return  fi.Length.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Any Suggestion??

Comment: I suggest you start with some more civilized indenting.  It's painful to look at in its current form.

Comment: You should be able to make readable code without knowing much about linq, especially since I just did.

Comment: You take difference1, then you order it, then you enumerate it to find out if it has more than 1 item. Order it later and use Any()

Comment: @Yuriy Faktorovich:ok fine..i dont know where to use any()...other than this whether the code is looking good??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that your goal is to get a list of files with unique lengths.  If so, I would go straight to the hash set (which gets used under the covers anyway if memory serves) and skip LINQ.

```
var uniqueFiles = new HashSet<FileInfo>(list1, new FileCompareLength());
uniqueFiles.SymmetricExceptWith(list2);
//you should now have the desired list.
//as mentioned in the comments, check for any items before sorting
if (uniqueFiles.Any())
{
    for (var file in uniqueFiles.OrderBy(x => x.Name))
    {
        //do stuff with file
    }
}
```

If you use the HashSet, you could also use Count since it would not involve iterating the entire collection as it did in your example, but I find that Any conveys intent just as well and is less likely to degrade performance due to small changes elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

After looking into your code, I find that you are using fussy methods. Since you are comparing `FileInfo.Length`, I'll use `int[]` as an example. Let's say:

```
list1:  1 2 2 5 5 7 (the numbers are lengths of files)
list2:  2 3 4 7
list1 except list2(called e1): 1 5 5 
list2 except list1(called e2): 3 4
SymmetricExceptWith: 1 5 5 3 4 (always e1+e2 because e1/e2 comes from Except)
```

Thus the code can be improved like:

```
var common = list1.Intersect(list2, myFileCompare1);
var exclusive = list1.Concat(list2).Where(x => !common.Contains(x))
                                   .OrderBy(x => x.Name);
```

Comment: i need files with different length